# Algorithm for a variation of 2d bin packing

Tags: algorithm, packing

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve the following problem.

Let's say we have a container having fixed width and infinite length. We also have a set of rectangular packages (in my case no more than 625).

The point is to find an arrangment with the smallest possible length (length is measured as in the "picture"). Packages can be rotated, but cannot overlap.

I'm looking for anything: algorithms (preferably), pointers, advice, or suggestion. Width of the container is fixed.

```
 |<--------Length----->|
-+------------------+--+------------------->>>
W|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
i|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
d|-------+-----+----+--+
t|XXXXXXX|XXXXX|XXXXXXX|
h|XXXXXXX+-----+----+--+
 |XXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXX|
-+-------+----------+---------------------->>>
```

Comment: From the picture, the length you are trying to minimize seems like the width. In that case, puting 1 package under the other is optimal, will just use more height from other solutions

Comment: Isn't that variation of [cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output.

Comment: It will be helpful to play around with it.

Comment: Indeed looks like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem. Are you looking for a more specific pointers?